# Passing an incremental int between functions in Python

Tags: python

I am new to programming and I have recently started learning Python (through a udemy course). The latest project was building a Blackjack card game and I have been trying to add other features, such as a win/loss tracker.
For that purpose, I am trying to increment a variable (b_count) as win counter. However I can't figure out how to pass it from module1 to module2 (the former being called from the later).

Here is a boiled down code:
I want b_count printed from module2 to increment by 1 each time the player wins (represented below by a == 2). It should start at 0 and increment when the player decides to replay the game (when module2 is called by itself).

```
import random
b_count = 0
game_count = 1

def module1(b_count):
  a = random.randint(1,3)
  print(f"a = {a}")
  if a == 2:
    b_count += 1

def module2(b_count, game_count):
  print(f"b_count: {b_count}")
  print(f"game_count: {game_count}")
  module1(b_count)
  
  replay = input("replay? y/n: ")
  if replay == "y":
    game_count += 1
    module2(b_count, game_count)

module2(b_count, game_count)
```

I have tried adding the parameters to the functions, but b_count as printed in module2 never increments, even when a == 2.The game counter works though.
I have read about passing variables, but I am a bit stuck.
Is there a way to specifically pass to module2 the value of b_count from module1?

```
return b_count
```

in module1 did not help.
I also tried something like:

```
 print(f"\nb_count: {module1(b_count)}")
```

but that did not help either.

It seems like an easy thing to do and it is probably a beginner's mistake. I also keep reading that using global variables is frown upon, so I am trying to figure a way around that.

Could someone shed some light on this?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def module1(b_count):
  a = random.randint(1,3)
  print(f"a = {a}")
  if a == 2:
    b_count += 1
```

Incrementing `b_count` is purely a local change here; it has no effect on the variable that was passed in.

You'll need to either *return* the variable back to the caller and handle it appropriately there, or make it a global.

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to find a solution besides using a global variable, but at least doing so fixed my problem.